# update Sql Calculation statement

Tags: sql

May i know how to update Sql Calculation statement ?

For example i want to update the sum tatal to the table

Below is the code

```
 SELECT p.Qty AS pQty,
       SUM(t.Qty) AS tQty,
       p.Qty - SUM(t.Qty) AS total ,
       p.PName
FROM tblTempTransaction t ,
     tblProducts p
WHERE t.UserID= 2
  AND t.OrderID=1
  AND p.pid = t.pid
GROUP BY t.UserID,
         p.qty ,
         p.PName ,
         t.OrderID

UPDATE tblProducts
SET qty = p.Qty - SUM(t.Qty)
WHERE t.UserID= 2
  AND t.OrderID=1
  AND p.pid = t.pid
GROUP BY t.UserID,
         p.qty ,
         p.PName ,
         t.OrderID
```

I will get the error from set qty = p.Qty - SUM(t.Qty)

May i know how to solve this ?
Thanks.

Comment: What RDBMS (MySql, SQL Server, Oracle, ...) are you using? `UPDATE` syntax is vendor specific.

Comment: @Victor Tang  where have you declared alias `p` and `t`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that youre query is correct.. you forgot to put 'from'

```
  UPDATE tblProducts
     SET qty = p.Qty - sq.total from (select SUM(t.Qty) as total from "table" as t
   WHERE t.UserID= 2 and t.OrderID=1 and p.pid = t.pid
GROUP BY t.UserID, p.qty ,p.PName ,t.OrderID) as sq
```

Comment: @Mobstaa how will you specify what is '"t"' from the update can you pls tell me?

Comment: FROM tblTempTransaction t

Comment: @Victortang its the name of the subquery

Comment: @Victortan ...Do you need the output from the select query?